# How can I use a .NET EventHandler to return a parameter into a specific variable?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, eventhandler

I am using the `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` of the `SerialPort` class for communicating with a serial port device. I send a SCPI code to the device by `SerialPortObject.Write(command)` where command is a string type. Then the device will reply with a string that is collected by the event handler and is read into a variable by `SerialPortObject.ReadLine()`.

I send different commands to the serial port e.g. to acquire the speed or position of a stepper motor and want to store them in `string speed` or `string position` respectively. However, the event handler can only read the line sent by the device without knowing which variable it should store the data in. A solution is to type the `SerialPortObject.ReadLine()` command after each `SerialPortObject.Write()` command, however, this pauses the thread and the Windows From halts until the device responds which sometimes might be long, while the event handler will do this asynchronously.

```
string position, speed;
SerialPortObject.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var input = SerialPortObject.ReadLine();
    }
public void CurrentPosition()
    {
        //This requests for the current position (command is specific to the device)
        SerialPortObject.Write("?X");
    }
public void Speed()
    {
        //This requests for the current position (command is specific to the device)
        SerialPortObject.Write("?V");
    }
```

**My question**
How can I have the `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` to recognize which of the `CurrentPosition()` or `Speed()` raised the event and put the device response into the `position` and `speed` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep state of which command was last send eg with an enum.
Or the sending side should add (if posible) the parameter which was requested.